# Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities

Tags: android, google-console-developer

Google Console says that my app isn't optimized for Tablets

> Design your app for tablets
>
> Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:
>
> Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet
>   screen densities

I my **res** folder I have next **drawable** folders:

```
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

**drawable** folder contains 76 PNGs and 48 XMLs
**drawable-hdpi**, **drawable-xhdpi**, **drawable-xxhdpi**, **drawable-xxxhdpi** folders contain 76 PNGs but size (width x height) are different

Comment: same here, how to complete this tip?